# Parsing XML using JQuery and PhoneGap

Tags: jquery, xml

I know my question might be asked previously couple times. I tried many solution but it didn't work for me.

I am trying to build a mobile app using JQuery and PhoneGap that get data from XML file .

This is my XML file:

```
<book>
<chapter id="1">
<title>title 1</title>
<question id="1.1"> Question 1 </question>
<answer id="1.1.1"> answer for q1 </answer>
</chapter>

<chapter id="2">
<title>title 2</title>
<question id="2.1"> Question 2 </question>
<answer id="1.2.1"> answer for q2 </answer>
</chapter>
</book>
```

and this is my JavaScript:

```
$(document).bind("pageshow", function() {

$.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url:'Book.xml',
        datatype:'xml',
        success:function(xml){
            alert("success");
        }
    });
});
```

If I have a function the success alert never shown, however if the alert is shown in this code
   $(document).bind("pageshow", function() {

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url:'Book.xml',
        datatype:'xml',
        success: alert("success");

    });
});
```

I am stuck here as I can't add any further code.

Comment: This is what I got in the console
XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///Book.xml. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Answer (score 0):

The second version is simply calling `alert` and assigning the return value (`undefined`) to the success member. That is why you see the alert message box.

The first version could be failing for any number of reasons. First you should confirm that you are in fact receiving data back (e.g. by using the developer tools in the browser)